# Using a picture as wallpaper in different view

Tags: android-10, wallpaper

Whenever we use a picture as wallpaper, it appears as a full screen. Mostly, in full screen, the picture is not completely visible.

Can I use a picture as wallpaper in different views like as a centre, or as tiles,… so that picture should be in short size at the centre?

Please let me know, how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I'm not sure if the built-in wallpaper feature allows this on any Android device. Probably needs a 3rd-party wallpaper utility app to achieve this (hasn't researched anything though)